# Possible for Blade not to escape certain html tags?

Tags: laravel-5.1, laravel-blade

In Laravel Blade, `{{...}}` will escape all HTML tags.

Is it possible to exclude certain tags from being escaped, such as `<p>` or `<br/>`? While I can just `{!!...!!}}`, it will allow any tags to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

you should go to
`vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\Compilers\BladeCompiler.php`
and chang this function

```
    protected function compileRawEchos($value)
{
    $pattern = sprintf('/(@)?%s\s*(.+?)\s*%s(\r?\n)?/s', $this->rawTags[0], $this->rawTags[1]);

    $callback = function ($matches) {
        $whitespace = empty($matches[3]) ? '' : $matches[3].$matches[3];

        return $matches[1] ? substr($matches[0], 1) : '<?php echo '.$this->compileEchoDefaults($matches[2]).'; ?>'.$whitespace;
    };

    return preg_replace_callback($pattern, $callback, $value);
}
```